# Unable to obtain Firebase ID on iOS using BrowserStack

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, browserstack

When testing a Mobile Application on BrowserStack (App Live) on iOS devices I am unable to obtain a Firebase ID, which we use for sending push notifications to both iOS and Android devices.

The Firebase ID can however be obtained as expected using a physical iOS device which makes me assume it could possibly be a BrowserStack issue? I am also able to obtain a Firebase ID when using an Android device on BrowserStack.

I should also add that both our applications are native apps, not sure if this could have any impact.